# Gerrit: is there a way to push just the top commit to the same branch?

Tags: git, gerrit

After searching for a light and finding quite a few similar questions, none of them seemed to really answer my question (below a list of related questions I found).

I am developing further changes on top of a commit not yet reviewed, but I want to keep the changes separate. When trying to push the new patch for review, I get the error:

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no changes made)
```

**Scenario:**
In my branch I have Commit A (merged)  <-- Commit B (cherry-picked/unmerged)
<-- Commit C (with recent changes I want to push).

As mentioned, Commit C is dependent of B (but as I want them separate, a squash cannot be done. Also removing B is not an option, as it adds changes not yet present is C).

So when I try to push Commit C for review I get the error message above (I understand that is due to Commit B being below the new Commit C).

My question is: is there a way to send **only** Commit C up to Gerrit, before Commit B gets merged? Or I really must wait for B to be merged so I can send Commit C up?

**Homework:**

[Gerrit workflow - push single commit to topic branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785416/gerrit-workflow-push-single-commit-to-topic-branch)

[Git / gerrit, push remote rejected no changes made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992229/git-gerrit-push-remote-rejected-no-changes-made)

[Is there a way to force Gerrit to have all commits in a branch be push to code review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473074/is-there-a-way-to-force-gerrit-to-have-all-commits-in-a-branch-be-push-to-code-r)

[git - pushing only the top most commit to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206630/git-pushing-only-the-top-most-commit-to-server)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can push commit-C based on unmerged commit-B but you can't cherry-pick it because that way you get commit-C based on commit-B' (a different commit which has no changes when compared with original commit-B.

Try this procedure:

1. Checkout the unmerged commit-B (copy this command from Gerrit > Change > Download > Checkout):

   git fetch https://USER@SERVER/a/REPO-PATH/REPO-NAME refs/changes/X/Y/Z && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
2. Create a branch from commit-B

   git checkout -b some-branch
3. Make commit-C change, commit and push to Gerrit

I think Gerrit will create a change with commit-C based on commit-B from previous change. Be aware that if someone change the original commit-B you will need to rebase your commit-C before it can be merged.

Comment: what is the git push command to use here? In our org we normally do `git push <remotename> HEAD:<remotebranchname>` and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: So initially i was using the cherry-pick option to get the commit-B locally, after using the git pull option, I am able to push the commit-C for review.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to simply combine (squash) both commits into one while you are developing (in a separate change-set from B) and once B is merged you can rebase on top of master which will just leave your unique changes.